# How to set DefaultText of TextBox in Windows Forms application?

Tags: winforms, textbox

[From MSDN entry for `Control.ResetText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resettext.aspx):

> Resets the Text property to its default value.

Stupid question, but I can't find where I can set this "default value". When I invoke `ResetText()` on `TextBox` all text is simply cleared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value used by `ResetText` in the `TextBox`control is not configurable and it happens to be the `string.Empty` so that's why when you invoke the method the text is cleared.

However, since the `ResetText` method is virtual you can do the following:

```
class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public override void ResetText()
    {
        this.Text = "MyDefaultText";
    }
}
```

Now, you just need to use your `MyTextBox` instead of the `TextBox` control. This is of course complicating things just for the sake of setting the `Text` property, so you are better of by assigning your default text directly to the `Text` property if you have no requirements to support a default value specifically through the use of `ResetText`.

Answer (score 0):

That method is used within the designers. So unless you are not writing a designer with this control you need not worry about it. Runtime default value is empty string.